# Scrapy Image Pipeline

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, scrapy

I've written the following function in the spider to scrape info in a website. I've enabled the Image pipelines to even scrape the image along with the associated scraped data. With this piece of code i'm able to yield either the images or the `scraped_data` (which is commented in the last second line). Can anyone please help me with this as how can i yield both the images and the `scraped_info`?

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    url = response.url
    title = str(response.xpath('//*[@dataitem="itemTitle"]/text()').extract_first())
    img_url_1 = response.xpath("//img[@id='icImg']/@src").extract_first()
    scraped_info = {
        'title' : title,
    }
    yield {'image_urls': [img_url_1]}
```

I've checked running this code for scraping images which was successful. Thus, there's no error in `settings.py` or `items.py`. I'm concerned about scraping the images with the scraped data together. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) to Image Pipeline, items that you yield have to contain field `image_urls` (as a list). The Image Pipeline will download the images and populate another field of the item - `images` - with information about downloaded images.

Thus, you have to modify your code like this (showing only the relevant part):

```
def parse_info(self, response):
    item = response.meta.get('item')
    url=response.url
    title=str(response.xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]/text()').extract_first())
    img_urls=response.xpath("//img[@id='icImg']/@src").extract()
    scraped_info = {
        'url' : url,
        'title' : title,
        'image_urls' : img_urls
    }
    yield scraped_info
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomáš for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should just yield an item that contains both the info and the image urls:

```
yield {
    'url' : url,
    'title' : title,
    'image_urls': [img_url_1]
}
```